# ESP8266EX along with Arduino Due rev3 to check wifi status

Tags: arduino-due

Hi i am using ESP8266EX along with Arduino Due rev3 to check wifi status. when i compile my following sketch compiler give me error
User\Awais\Document\Arduino\liberaries\espsoftserialmaster\softserial.cpp:27:18: fatal error: gpio.h: no file or directory found
any one help me solve this problem

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial ESPserial (15,14); //RX|TX


     void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  Serial.begin(115200);
  ESPserial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("NL & CR");
}

  void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if (ESPserial.available()){
   Serial.write(ESPserial.read());
  }

if (Serial.available()){
ESPserial.write(Serial.read());
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

And where did you get that SoftwareSerial library? SoftwareSerial libraries are architecture dependent. You can't use AVR ore esp8266 SoftwareSerial library with ARM.

Due has no need for SoftwareSerial, it has 4 Serial ports configured.